# How to remotely check if SSL 3.0 is enabled on server?

Tags: tls, ip, server, nmap

I would like to remotely verify whether SSL 3.0 is running on several servers.

Previously, this command:

`openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -ssl3`

Would have worked but now I am getting the error `Option unknown option -ssl3` meaning that the flag is not available in my build of `openssl`.

Found the same issue noted here:

https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/6801

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=766297

Running `nmap` with grep is not an option.

My question is: Is there any other way to verify whether SSL is enabled by pointing to the server IP?

Comment: Drop the `-ssl3`.

Comment: Do you really need SSL v3? Not TLS 1, not TLS 1.1, not TLS 1.2, not TLS 1.3?

Comment: The command you gave was used to check specifically for SSL 3.0, not for SSL in general terms (i.e. SSL/TLS). I've therefore changed your question to make clear that you want to check for the obsolete SSL 3.0 specifically. If this was not your intention then you've used the wrong command in the first place.

Comment: Just on the off-chance this is related to today's vulnerability release, it's worth noting that SSLv3 is nothing to do with OpenSSLv3 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the tool [`testssl.sh`](https://github.com/drwetter/testssl.sh) to check if and which SSL and TLS versions are available.

Clone the GitHub repository, then call the tool like so:

```
./testssl.sh https://example.com/
```

This will tell you exactly:

- which versions of SSL/TLS you are using,
- which ciphers are configured for each version,
- whether or not any of these are considered "weak",
- if your server shows any SSL/TLS vulnerabilities (Heartbleed, CCS, etc.)
- which cipher each client would likely use

Comment: Sorry for taking forever to accept this answer. Thank you for your response, that tool has been helpful in other times as well.